# Why am I getting a 403 status when using requests VS urllib2?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, python-2.x

My request works fine when using urllib2, but I get a 403 error when using requests instead.

```
import urllib2

   url = 'https://api.optconnect.com/summit/beta/accounts/login/app_secret'
   data = {'accountId': 000,
        'applicationId': 000,
        'secret': '000'}
   data = json.dumps(data)
   headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json' }
   req = urllib2.Request(url, data ,headers)
   response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   print(response.getcode())
```

> 200

```
import requests


   url = 'https://api.optconnect.com/summit/beta/accounts/login/app_secret'
   data = {'accountId': 000,
        'applicationId': 000,
        'secret': '000'}
   data = json.dumps(data)
   headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json' }
   req = requests.get(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
   print(req.status_code)
```

> 403

Comment: This doesn't seem like much to go on. Can you reproduce it on a URI you can share? If you can capture the requests on the wire, are they identical?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Can't really capture SSL on the wire, at least not in a way that's easy to inspect without a mitm.

Comment: It seems you're using the `.get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked

```
req = requests.request("POST", url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
req = requests.get(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

try

```
req = requests.post(url=url, data=data)
```

Comment: why do I get an downvote for this answer? Please comment on downvotes..

Comment: Thanks! That didn't work either but it was close to what worked. Thanks for your contribution! (I don't know why there was a down vote)